# Laravel Socialite Linkedin Login Not Working

Tags: laravel, linkedin-api, laravel-9, laravel-socialite

I have been trying to login through linkedin for my application there are few issues

1. First that while redirecting it is accepting old scopes that were used in oauth1 but now im using oauth2 but it is accepting scopes as **r_emailaddress** and **r_liteprofile** as you can see in attached image this i can bypass by entering **email,profile,openid** insted of this then i get popup to authorize this app [click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVtWH.png)
   but after that also if i use stateless it gives me the [enter click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vykpC.png) error of [click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyHzg.png)  can anyone help ?

```
HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
Client error: `POST https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed"}
```

I have tried stateless and web middleware both but it is not working in both case i have verified the app and did everything possible but stuck in this loop kindly help im on laravel 9 using socialite package

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Socialite version 5, and
Change in service.php

```
“linkedin”:[
To
“linkedin-openapi”:[
```